# Richardson's Methods

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to prove Richardson's Method and the first part of the proof is:

Consider the linear system $Ax = b$ where the eigenvalues of $A$ are real and positive.  Let $G_{\omega } = I - \omega A$, where $\omega$ is a scalar.
Let the iteration be $$x^{n+1} = (I-\omega A)x^{n} +\omega b$$

Show all the eigenvalues of $G_{\omega}$ are less than one.

Show that Richardson's method converges iff $\omega$ < $\frac{2}{\lambda _{max}} $

I have to show all the eigenvalues of $G_{\omega}$ are less than one. without knowing about convergence because I will use this later on in the proof to prove that it does converge which is kind of the problem I'm having.

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial, then the eigenvalues of $P(A)$ are $P(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. So the eigenvalues of $G_\omega$ are $1-\omega \lambda$ which will be less than $1$ (but maybe not less than $1$ in absolute value) provided $\omega>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda \in \mathbf C$ be an eigenvalue of $G_\omega$, with corresponding eigenvector $x \in \mathbf C^n$. Then 
$$ G_\omega x  =\lambda x \iff x - \omega Ax = \lambda x \iff Ax = \frac{1 - \lambda}{\omega} x $$ 
So, $\frac{1-\lambda}{\omega}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, hence $\frac{1-\lambda}\omega > 0$, giving $\lambda < 1$.

To prove that the iteration converges, it suffices to show that all eigenvalues of $G_\omega$ are bounded in absolute value(!) by 1, that is, showing that they are also larger than $-1$.